# visual studio 2013 express Windows Store tab disable

Tags: visual-studio-2013, windows-phone, windows-store-apps

I make a windows phone app with visual studio 2013 express, and now I would like to publish my app on the windows store. So I have ta package my project but in my visual studio I have a WINDOWS STORE tab but is disable, What going on? I have to do something before to active this tab?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you have a Windows Phone Silverlight app. Silverlight apps are not explicitly packaged. You will upload the Xap file created when doing a release build to the Windows Phone Store.

Windows Runtime apps are packaged explicitly from the Store menu and then uploaded to the Windows Store  or the Windows Phone Store.

I go into more details on this in my blog entry [Why can’t I create an app package? Windows Phone Xap vs. Appx](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wsdevsol/archive/2014/08/07/why-can-t-i-create-an-app-package-windows-phone-xap-vs-appx.aspx)